# How do I lazy load a property?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lazy-loading

I have a POCO class that is mostly built through a service. I hit the service with some info, get back a dto and use that to build parts of the object. What I'm trying to do is lazy load some of the bigger properties so that they're only filled on demand. I thought this was the way to do it:

```
        private List<User> _directReports;
        public List<User>DirectReports
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._directReports == null)
                {
                    SetDirectReports();
                }
                return this._directReports;
            }
            private set
            {
                this._directReports = value;
            }
        }

        private void SetDirectReports()
        {
            using (var client = new ADSClient())
            {
                this._directReports = client.GetDirectReports(this.Guid);
            }
        }
```

Here's the problem, and maybe I'm chasing ghosts, but when I step through debugger and look at the guts of the object after instantiating it, those fields have information in it, and it shouldn't at that stage and completely defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. So I'm trying to understand this, am I doing this wrong? Is the compiler running the get method as some point that I'm not thinking about?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (long day) but doesn't your get accessor cause _directReports to be updated?  And isn't the get accessor called by the debugger?  So if my brain is working correctly today then observing the property's state using the debugger actually changes its state.

Comment: That's the point... update _directReports and return it, if it was not yet initialized.

Comment: maybe i dont understand you correctly, but when you are saying you are looking at the fields you mean _directReports, or DirectReports?

Comment: _directReports was showing values withing the get being called. It was a ghost though. Very misleading.

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah I assumed I must be missing something because it seemed so obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a debugger artifact.  When you use a watch or a quick inspect to look at the property, the debugger will run the property getter so it can display its value.  Which causes your lazy init code to execute.  So you'll never see the property return null.

Something to keep in mind.

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking (chasing ghosts). I was debugging do to a different error and noticed this. Now that I fixed the bug, the values are displaying as null like they should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there isn't a user waiting unnecessarily long when an expensive property is accessed, and assuming expensive properties are not accessed in every run, this works fine.

If either of those conditions are not given, you may want to consider initializing "expensive" properties in the background.

If the foreground task (e.g. UI) accesses a property before a background task had a chance to initialize it, the property access would block until the property is initialized.

An improvement would be to inform the background initialization task that the particular property is now required so that it can be initialized next.  Alternatively, coordinate between the foreground and background task that the foreground task will take over initialization of this expensive property.

Comment: what I'm actually doing is lazy loading any property that comes back over 16k on average. These service calls have to hit active directory over a WCF service, so I'm basically lazy loading all collections otherwise it is dirt slow.